# DateTime.Parse False positives with string containing dotted separated numbers

Tags: c#, date

I'm parsing datetimes from a text read from SQL Server using `DateTime.Parse`.

String like these:

```
5.4.1 
1.1.4 
12.1.13
```

were identified as dates, while they are not.

I can't use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, since I have to load data in different formats:

```
dd/mm/yy
dd/mm/yyyy
dd MMM YYYY
dd-mm-yyyy
dd.mm.yyyy
```

How can I parse dates according to those formats, while ignoring values like shown above?

Comment: _iam parsing datetime from text read from sql server_ What do you mean by that? Why you _can't_ use `DateTime.TryParseExact`? Is there any special reason? Based on your inputs, looks like `d.M.y` and `d.M.yy` formats are fine.

Comment: @gt.guybrush you have to specify all formats, see my answer where this is applied.

Comment: honestly I was hoping to avoid having to specify each allowable format, but since I see no alternative follow this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use the dates you have specified you can reach a result with the code below.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx since it is very well explained.

```
string[] formats= {"dd/MM/yy","dd/MM/yyyy","dd MMM YYYY","dd-MM-yyyy","dd.MM.yyyy","dd.M.yy","d.M.y"};
  string[] dateStrings = {"5.4.1","1.1.4","12.1.13"}; 
  DateTime dateValue;
  foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
  {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                out dateValue))
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
     else
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
```

This code will result in:

> Converted '5.4.1' to 1/5/2001 12:04:00 AM.
>
> Converted '1.1.4' to 1/1/2004 12:01:00 AM.
>
> Converted '12.1.13' to 1/12/2013 12:01:00 AM.

**Please notice the cultureinfo! This can give different outputs according to it's setting. For example: month and date can be switched!**

Ps. You can immediately try this working snippet on http://csharppad.com/.

Comment: The op's idea was to explicitely not parse these formats: `"dd.M.yy","d.M.y"`. You should remove those from your formats variable to prevent they get parsed.

Comment: with Marwie comment i accept this as solution over @CodeCaster one's for CultureInfo notice

Answer (score 3):

You *can* let dates be parsed according to your expected formats. Just pass the  (fixed, mm != MM) formats to `TryParseExact()`:

```
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd MMM YYYY", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy" };

string[] dateStrings = { "5.4.1", "1.1.4", "12.1.13", "23.02.2016" };

foreach (var dateString in dateStrings)
{
    DateTime parsedDate;        

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was parsed as a valid DateTime: {1}", dateString, parsedDate);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was not parsed as a valid DateTime.", dateString);
    }
}
```